# Would that be a practicable way for a kind of 'finally' block in VBA?

Tags: vba, error-handling

This sample is taken from [Can I Return From The Current Event Stack In Microsoft Access VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492590/can-i-return-from-the-current-event-stack-in-microsoft-access-vba)

I reworked it a bit to show the idea I got from reading the mentioned article.

Sure, usually I wouldn't use GoSub at all, but in this case I see no other way.

The goal is to have clean-up code at one place in a method which will be executed in all situations, also before (re-)raising an error myself.

```
Sub DoSomething()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Dim fileNumber As Long
    fileNumber = FreeFile
    'do stuff
    '...

CleanExit:
    GoSub CleanFinally
    Exit Sub

CleanFinally:
    On Error Resume Next
    Close fileNumber
    On Error Goto 0
    Return

CleanFail:
    If Err.Number = 53 Then
        ' handle "file not found" error
        Resume CleanExit
    Else
        Dim errNumber As Long
        errNumber = Err.Number 
        GoSub CleanFinally
        Err.Raise errNumber ' rethrow
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems a reasonable use of subroutines, although I've never seen `Close` raise an error so `On Error Resume Next` / `GoTo 0` in the `CleanFinally` subroutine doesn't seem warranted. What's the question? If you have real code using this, [codereview.se] would probably be a better place to get feedback. As is stands though, it would probably be closed as "hypothetical code" given it's pretty much boiled-down.

Comment: You might want to put that in the [VBA Error Handling documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3211/error-handling#t=20170304192056101207); Documentation.SO has support for discussions about the topics, which seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: seems like overkill compared to just checking if the file exists, and I feel like generalising error handling leads to more problems than solutions

Comment: @Mat's Mug, Slai: As I wrote this is a sample which was taken from a different topic. It is just a "hypothetical code" to enable a Kind of "try-catch-finally" error handler in VBA. Unfortunately it is not very elegant, but seems to work. The `Resume Next`/`GoTo 0`is just to ensure that any content of the finally block won't raise an error itself.

Comment: @Mat's Mug: How should I add this to the mentioned article? As it is, as a suggestion? Don't want to 'break' anything. ;-)